# Вырезание лишнего поддомена через htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Есть ссылки вида название_города.site.ru/....
В этом случае все хорошо, но в некоторых случаях пользователь может ввести адрес город1.город2.site.ru/... или даже город1.город2.город3.site.ru/... Такие страницы попадают в индексацию поиску, что очень плохо. Как с помощью htaccess url такого вида перенаправить на город1.site.ru/..? Т.е отбросить промежуточные поддомены.

Answer (score 0):

Пробуйте так

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\..+\.SITE\.ru$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.SITE.ru/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

где `SITE` имя домена.

P.S. с `www.` могут быть проблемы.

Comment: Примерно так и думал, но запутался с регуляркой. спасибо! Такой вариант вроде работает.

Comment: Не работает в случаях когда есть путь за доменом: путь city1.city2.site/cat/201195 преобразуется в city1.site/index.php//201195/ Что делать в этих случаях?

Comment: @РадикХайруллин, попробуйте так. Возможно, у вас есть другие правила в .htaccess, которые вносят свои изменения.